# Why did "they" rely on cooper and his daughter to save themselves in Interstellar

Tags: plot-explanation, interstellar

If "they" were our descendants who transcended to the 5th dimension, "they" are practically a Godlike civilization compared to us, then why did they developed this complicated plan rather than simply communicating with NASA and send the equations to save the earth? I mean, Cooper nearly died on several occasions, and if these guys are our descendants, they were practically playing roulette with their own survival.

Comment: To simply put, "they" exists because of Cooper and Murphy. :-)

Comment: Ahhh, ok, thx.

PS: Sry, didn't it was duplicated.

Comment: @cursillosonline No problem, closing as duplicate is nothing inherently bad, just a way to point you to the proper answers for your question.